# oozie java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: hdfs

Tags: hadoop, oozie, hadoop-streaming, oozie-coordinator, oozie-workflow

I have setup the oozie 4.3.1 with Hadoop 2.7.3.

oozie has been setup and running successfully and able to see web console http://localhost:11000/oozie/
and also confirm using oozie status command.

Issue 1:
While running the oozie examples after changing the job.properties with relevant details getting the error.
nameNode=hdfs://localhost:9000
jobTracker=localhost:8032

```
bin/oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -config $OOZIE_HOME/examples/apps/map-reduce/job.properties -run
```

`Error: E0902 : E0902: Exception occured: [No FileSystem for scheme: hdfs]`

Issue 2: `oozie admin -sharelibupdate`

```
[ShareLib update status]
    host = http://f091403isdpbato05:11000/oozie
    status = java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: hdfs
```

hdfs path and other oozie related .xml files also updated with proper configurations.

Please let me know any solution to move ahead.

Comment: are you using a cloudera cluster ?

Comment: No i's on Hadoop cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the following to you core-site.xml :

```
<property>
   <name>fs.file.impl</name>
   <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem</value>
   <description>The FileSystem for file: uris.</description>
</property>

<property>
   <name>fs.hdfs.impl</name>
   <value>org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem</value>
   <description>The FileSystem for hdfs: uris.</description>
</property>
```

Comment: same has been already added, also have these properties set to oozie's core-site.xml      <property>
   <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>
    <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>
    <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.root.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
    </property>
    <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.root.groups</name>
    <value>*</value>
    </property>

Comment: did you add in your class path the hadoop-hdfs-client-2.7.3.jar ?